# Elementary question converting negative numbers to 0 in Java

Tags: java

I am working on a problem in a workbook about classes and part of it tells me to set negative numbers that pop up in my output to zero in order to make sense of it. Is it possible to accomplish this without using if/else statements or conditionals? I'd like to do this by only using print format, arithmetic and classes methods. No importing anything that isn't standard to java. Is this possible, am I missing something easy?

Comment: Conditional, including if/then statements are part of java.

Comment: May we use indexOf, as in, -1*(""+n).indexOf("-")*n?

Comment: No can't use index and I cant use if/else because it is next chapter. I think it's silly too, I've taken other languages and very frustrated I have to limit myself lol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **could** use [`Math.max(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-int-int-) - with parameters of `n` and `0` when the value `n` is negative that will result in `0`, otherwise `n`.

```
value = Math.max(0, value); // value is 0 if negative, otherwise value
```

Or, if using Java 8+, [`Integer.max(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#max-int-int-) for the same result

```
value = Integer.max(0, value);
```

Updating the original `value` shown for example purposes (it's entirely possible to use either solution here inline).

Comment: @itwasntme Question said *"**without** using if/else statements or **conditionals**"*. The `? :` is called a [**Conditional** Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), so Elliott did it right by not including that as an option in the answer.

Comment: @Andreas, ok. Since the `max(int,int)` method is using the ternary operator, so if an answer would contain the self-written method with that operator and later using it would be good? Prehaps, it wouldn't, what about recommending third party libs achieving it? In the huge edge case, making additional method call could cause some performance loss (but this is extremall case). Just to add the `Integer.max` just calls the `Math.max`

Comment: @itwasntme Question said *"No importing anything that isn't standard to java"*, so recommending third party libs is not it either. --- As for the rest of that comment, please be reasonable. If someone was told that they were not allowed to use loops, they had to use streams, would you then answer that that's impossible, because the stream framework uses loops internally? Of course not, so why say that you cannot use `max()` method because it uses conditionals internally? The restrictions are on the custom user-written code, so no I'd say you cannot write your own `max` either.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the ternary operator. No imports necessary.

Try this `number <= 0 ? 0 : number`

Of course, you will have to fine tune it to your use-case, but this is as simple as it gets.

You can read more about the ternary operator in Java here :- https://www.baeldung.com/java-ternary-operator

Edit: Eliott's solution is more elegant. I will let this answer be though. :)

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure whether you are working with integers or doubles, but the basic idea here could be adapted either way. Indeed you can use math.

```
(n+Math.abs(n))/2
```

(or possible /2.0, you may play with it depending on your context) should do the trick. Where n is positive 2n over 2 is just n again. Where n is negative, n + Math.abs(n) is 0, and 0 over 2 is still 0.

Comment: Any reason to use it insead of others? It seems like it just adds unnecessary operations.

Comment: Not especially. It just seemed more straight math (yes, I know max is in math, but this is a function people encounter in Algebra 1)

Comment: Yeah, not only in "Algebra 1" but somethimes in secondary schools, regardless, the operation it adds seems like walking from NY to LA through Toronto :D And I'm not saying it isn't a valid answer to that question.

Comment: So ((0.5*Math.signum(n)*Math.signum(n)+0.5*Math.signum(n)))*n is like going through Greenland?

Comment: Yeah and probably it gives few steps through Tokyo and Paris :)

Comment: Here's the problem with this one the numbers aren't always negative =/

Comment: @JamesShelton, I don't understand. Can you give an example of a number for which the above (in the box, though I claim the crazy one with signum also works) does not work?

Comment: Sorry didn't think it through it works. Had a brain lapse my bad lol thanks for the idea.